# xe:calendarView - How to change background color?

Tags: xpages

How to change the background color of an entry in xe:calendarView according to the type/Status of an appointment?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should check out the following classes

```
.s-cv-entry-innerframe{background-color:red}
.s-cv-text{color:#FFF}
```

you may need to override other classes as well, look for this file

c:\Notes\framework\shared\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino_8.5.3.20111208-0717.jar\resources\web\dwa\cv\themes\hannover\calendarView.css